# Windows 10 suddenly becoming laggy?

Tags: windows-10, performance, nvidia-graphics-card, lag

I have had Windows 10 (64-bit Pro) installed for about 3-4 months, and have had a wonderful experience until now. Yesterday I was in the middle of a game when all of a sudden it started becoming laggy. When this happened, I restarted the computer, yet the lag persisted. Here are my system specs:

- Intel i7-920 Quad-Core (8 Threads) @ 2.67 GHz
- Nvidia GT-630
- 5 GB DDR3 RAM
- 512 GB ADATA SSD
- 500 Watt Generic PSU

I have no clue why this began, and have not been able to fix it. Here is a list of things I have done to try to fix it:

- Run the memory diagnostic tool (no errors)
- Run Intel's CPU diagnostic tool (no errors)
- Downloaded and installed the latest driver for my GPU

Is there anything I can do at this point? I would rather not reinstall Windows, but if that's the only option then I can do that.

EDIT: The lag is definitely client-side. Any sort of game that I play is hindered by it (even offline single-player games like Super Meat Boy). I have very good internet (10-11 MB/s good)

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "laggy", or "lag" which is often used instead of "latency", doesn't really apply to the performance of an operating system.

Comment: Considering how often Windows 10 updates, I would recommend you first update **_all_** your drivers to the most recent version and then work your way from there.

Comment: @Ramhound Any lag is client-side, I have very good internet. It affects both multi- and single-player games.

Comment: @Creep2DJ - I understand.  I am trying to highlight the fact, you telling us Windows has latency ("it's laggy") doesn't make much sense.  I am trying to get you to use something other then the word laggy because that isn't a descriptive word.

Comment: @Ramhound I see. Is "jittery" a better word to describe it?

Comment: Does this "lag" or "jitter" only happen in games? What about watching Netflix? Is the entire computer running slow or is it only certain programs? Have you checked Task Manager for processes that are running lots of CPU or Memory?

Comment: @music2myear I have checked in Task Manager, and when this happened there wasn't really an issue with any of that. About 65% of my RAM was being used, and very little of my CPU was being used.

Comment: @music2myear Also, it seems to only happen on programs that utilize the graphics card. Maybe that's just my imagination, but that's what it looks like.

Comment: Jitter also has a specific meaning.  Anyways, this delay, does it effect an operating like using the shorcut to display task manager?  If so that typically indicates that Windows is waiting on I/O events.

Comment: No. It only affects games.